# jQuery - Get only the unique values of checked checkboxes based on an attr value

Tags: jquery, distinct-values

I am looping through some checkboxes and executing .ajax call for each checked checkbox. The thing is that the name attribute of each checkbox might be duplicate. So I want to rin the .ajax only for the checkboxes with a unique name attribute.

**Here is my script**

```
var elements = $("input:checkbox:checked")

var i = 0;
doLoop();

function doLoop() {
    if ( i >= elements.length ) {
        return;
    }

    // To get the element we are up to: $(elements[i])
    let e = $(elements[i]);
    var id = e.attr('name');
    var val = e.val();
    $.ajax({
        async : false,
        url:"import.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{id:id, val:val},
        success:function(data) {
            //do some action
            i++
            doLoop()
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried to find some similar topics here but with no luck.

**So if I have the following checked checkboxes**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input selected-checkbox" value="some text 1" name="smalltalk">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input selected-checkbox" value="some text 2" name="smalltalk">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input selected-checkbox" value="some text 3" name="smalltalk">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input selected-checkbox" value="some text 4" name="smalltalk">
```

Instead of 4 .ajax calls for each name attribute smalltalk, it should make the call only once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `.serializeArray()` method to give you data for the entire form:

```
let data = $('form').serializeArray();
console.log( data );
```

Output:

```
[{
        "name": "smalltalk",
        "value": "some text 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "smalltalk",
        "value": "some text 3"
    },
    {
        "name": "other",
        "value": "some other text 2"
    },
    {
        "name": "other",
        "value": "some other text 4"
    }
]
```

Which you can reorganize according to your needs for example:

```
let groupedData = Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
    ...acc,
    [cur.name]: (acc[cur.name] || []).concat(cur.value)
}), {}));
console.log( groupedData );
```

Output:

```
[
    [
        "smalltalk",
        [
            "some text 1",
            "some text 3"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "other",
        [
            "some other text 2",
            "some other text 4"
        ]
    ]
]
```

**DEMO**

```js
let data = $('form').serializeArray();
console.log( data );
console.log( data.reduce((acc,cur) => ({...acc,[cur.name]:(acc[cur.name] || []).concat(cur.value)}),{}) );
console.log( Object.entries( data.reduce((acc,cur) => ({...acc,[cur.name]:(acc[cur.name] || []).concat(cur.value)}),{}) ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
SmallTalk
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input selected-checkbox" value="some text 1" name="smalltalk" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input selected-checkbox" value="some text 2" name="smalltalk">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input selected-checkbox" value="some text 3" name="smalltalk" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input selected-checkbox" value="some text 4" name="smalltalk">
<br><br>
Other
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input selected-checkbox" value="some other text 1" name="other">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input selected-checkbox" value="some other text 2" name="other" checked>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input selected-checkbox" value="some other text 3" name="other">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input selected-checkbox" value="some other text 4" name="other" checked>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I decided assign the value of the name attr inside the .ajax to another variable and then before the .ajax to check if the current match lasts. I will post an update.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with a simple (not sure how effective it is from a performance point of view) approach.

I have assigned the id value to another variable called cid (`cid = id;`) after the .ajax success, so I can have the last value that went through the .ajax, and then compare the new value in the loop with the last value (`if (id != cid) {`).

**So here is what I ended up with**

```
var elements = $("input:checkbox:checked")
var cid;
var i = 0;
doLoop();

function doLoop() {
    if ( i >= elements.length ) {
        return;
    }

    // To get the element we are up to: $(elements[i])
    let e = $(elements[i]);
    var id = e.attr('name');
    var val = e.val();
    if (id != cid) {
        $.ajax({
            async : false,
            url:"import.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{id:id, val:val},
            success:function(data) {
                cid = id;
                //do some action
                i++
                doLoop()
            } 
        });
    } else {
        s++;
        doiLoop();
        }
  }
```